# I am not able to show custom icon in my app using Kendo UI

Tags: android, kendo-ui, customization

I am not able to show custom icon in my app using kendo mobile. Here is my code

```
.km-root .km-pane .km-view .km-balance sheet 
{ background-size: 100% 100%; -webkit-background-clip: border-box; background-color: green; } 

.km-balance sheet { -webkit-mask-box-image: url("../../styles/images/balance_sheet.png"); background-color: red; }
```

Comment: what is `-webkit-mask-box-image` refer too? because am not heard about it in CSS?

Comment: that is style for using kendo mobile..CMIIW

Comment: Open web inspector and check if the styles are being overridden somehow. Did you try that?

Comment: Typically Kendo UI styles define `background` images also despite it seems that the are just a color. Try overriding it using `background: red;` -remove the background-image- and also try adding `!important;` at the end of `-webkit-mask-box-image` to prevent being overwritten.

Comment: Try to use `!important` at the end of `-webkit-background-clip` and `-webkit-mask-box-image` . And if `-webkit-background-clip: border-box;` does not work try using `-webkit-background-clip: content-box !important;`. I have used it in this manner and it worked.